# Requirements for a masters degree in pure mathematics

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

I am in the second year of a Bachelors of Science program in business administration and economics. My program is in English and I am studying in Sweden. I attended elementary school in Romania and high school, with major in economics and business administration, in Germany. In high school I selected computer science as a subject, which was optional, because I was interested in the world of computer science and its mysteries, especially that of programming. The programming language taught in the course, in high school, was visual basic. Currently I know C++, HTML, CSS and PHP, and some JQuery. I have been programming for about four years now. The book I used was C++ Primer by Stanley B. Lippman for most of my C++ knowledge and internet resources, and for the web development, HTML, CSS, and PHP, I mainly used w3schools.com and other internet resources, and of course practice.

The mathematics at high school included some linear algebra and calculus, both differentiation and integration, but at a computational level. After high school I was unsure which academic path I should follow, which led to a one year break between high school and university. During this year I attended as a guest, lectures in computer science and mathematics (mainly propositional logic, set theory and proofs) in Germany. Then I decided to follow a business administration and economics path as my Bachelor of Science and go back to pure mathematics in my Masters program. In my free time I work through mathematical books. I worked through Precalculus by Jeff Zeager and Carl Stitz, How to prove it: A structured approach by Daniel J. Velleman, Book of proof by Richard Hammack and I am currently going through Calculus by Michael Spivak, where I recently finished the Differentiation part of the book. And as from my experience so far, Spivak's book will stay with me for some more months to come before I finish it.

I will graduate with a Bachelor of Science degree in business administration and economics and after that I want to pursue a Masters degree in pure mathematics with major in computer science and physics, preferably. The only course which is of mathematical nature in my program, is "Business Statistics", which essentially is a course in statistics, but with business applications and exercises.

Long story short:

What are the requirements for a Masters program in pure mathematics, with preferable computer science and physics majors? Is it realistic to be accepted in a Masters program with a Bachelor of Science in economics and business administration? I already have knowledge from mathematics courses, which Bachelor of Science students in mathematics take, but I do not have proof for this knowledge, in form of a degree or courses passed. Will I have to somehow prove this knowledge when applying for a masters program? If yes, how? I want to avoid after the degree in business administration and economics to enroll into a Bachelor of Science in mathematics, because that would be redundant for me, if I already have the knowledge but it is not recognized, because it is not in form of a formal document.

PS:

I will graduate in 2018. My goals are to finish Calculus by Michael Spivak, start and finish Calculus Volume 2 by Tom Apostol, Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin and a book in linear algebra.

Comment: Short answer shorter: ask the graduate school you're interested in what are the requirements. Most probably economics + BA is way too little to get accepted.

Comment: @DonAntonio If I interpret it correctly, a human is bound to the path he/she chose after high school, even though his/her knowledge is broader and covers a greater horizon?

Comment: My two cents regarding your comment: If you want a masters in math, go get a BS or a BA in math and commit to it. Why are you getting a degree in business administration with essentially no mathematical component to the formal degree if your ultimate goal is an MS in math?

Comment: @T.Bongers My ultimate goal is a PhD in mathematics. To answer your question: Because I already majored in economics and business administration in high school, and I wanted to strengthen that basics with a BS. Because the knowledge in economics and business administration is applicable in every day life. You are part of the economy and knowing how businesses' work is a valuable skill one should know. Mathematics on the other hand is fundamental in every science, it occurs naturally in the world around us, and is a perfect science for postgraduate studies and research.

Comment: @Simpl0s I've no idea what you meant in your answer to me. I know that economy + BA is not enough, in general, to know mathematics at undergraduate school level, not to mention at graduate school level. Now, if you already havea bachelor in whatever **and** if you can prove you've the knowledge required to go to grad. school, then you have some chance...but I doubt it. Most serious schools have more or less stiff parameters for their students, so you'll probably have to take a BSc in mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose that while carrying on your studies for Bachelors of Science program in business administration and economics you keep studying math courses with a focus and orientation towards a high score in the GRE subject test in Mathematics. That might provide a good argument -for postgraduate applications-  against the lack of a formal degree in maths or a math related science. But again, you have to contact postgraduate departments of interest to you and directly ask their opinion, on whether a high score in GRE subject test in Mathematics will be enough and what more they might ask from you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and your time! I will contact the departments of interest and look into the GRE subject test. I have not heard of this test before and I am grateful that you mentioned it!